# Can't figure out where to start subclassing a UIControl!

Tags: iphone, uikit, subclassing, uicontrol

I want to create my own control that will consist of several UILabels and a couple of UITextFields. The problem is I'm not sure where to start! Do I directly subclass UIControl, then create my subviews and add them to the main view in init:? Or do I use layoutSubviews? And will I need to override drawRect:?

I'm used to creating "Controller" classes that will handle adding subviews but if I subclass UIControl then I'm not sure what methods to override to set things up!

I've never done this before so I'd really appreciate a few pointers!

Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure you want `UIControl`?  The `UIControl` class is intended for fairly simple, typically reusable controls like buttons and text fields that need to support a limited set of events (like "touched" or "value changed").  If you're just trying to create a way to group several views together, you should use `UIView` instead.

In either case, here's what you should do:

1. Create your subviews and set most of their properties in `-initWithFrame:`.  Save them in instance variables and add them as subviews of self.
2. Set their frames in `-layoutSubviews`, calculating them based on `self.bounds`.  This will be called any time your view changes size, including after `-initWithFrame:`.

You should not need to implement `-drawRect:` unless you need to do custom drawing with Core Graphics functions.

Comment: if you add subviews like UILabel in initWithFrame and set the frame in layoutSubviews, does that mean you can't use drawRect to further add UI elements like a line drawn underneath the UILabel?

Comment: You can use `-drawRect:` to do custom Core Graphics (or now, `UIBezierPath`) drawing.  However, this drawing will be below all subviews—if your subviews are opaque, the `-drawRect:` drawing will not be visible.  For a UILabel, for instance, you'll need to make sure its `backgroundColor` is `[UIColor clearColor]` and its `opaque` property is set to `NO`.